# Codeigniter - how to display data from the database where the 'where id = $ value'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm tried to make year reporting with codeigniter.
expectation output like this:
month 01 = 0 data, month 02 = 10 data and continuing...

**Controller**

```
$this->load->model('dash_model');

$data = array();
$data['mont'] = array$this->dash_model->monthreport();

$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
$this->parser->parse('blank.htm', $data);
```

When I'm trying to write the code in PHP without CodeIgniter, it does work.

```
for($i=1; $i<=12; )
{
    $month=array("","01","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
    $m = $month[$i];

    $query = "SELECT count(*) as trans_email 
              FROM trans_email 
              WHERE lup LIKE '2014-$m%' ";
    $qu = mysql_query($query);

    $data=mysql_fetch_array($qu);
    $komp = $data['trans_email'];
}
```

I tried to implement the above code to model CodeIgniter

**dash model**

```
 for($i=1; $i<=12; )
 {
     $month=array("","01","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
     $m = $month[$i];
     $query2=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*) as rr 
                               FROM trans_email 
                               WHERE lup LIKE '2014-$m%' ");

     $resultArray[$i]=$query2->result_array();

     $i++;
 }
 return $resultArray;
```

**View**

```
{mont}
month {rr}
{/mont}
```

and the results are not as expected.

How to return the query that was in an array of as many as 12 times and resulted in 12 outputs like this:
month 01 = 0 data, month 02 = 10 data and continuing...

**How to query that I have a loop, its value can I throw into the controller**

Comment: what are the results you are expecting, and what is it returning right now?

Comment: sry this question : how to return loop query into controller @SimonFredsted

Comment: where in your model did you put the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what i would do:

```
 $months = array(
     '01',
     '02',
      ...
     );
 $this->db->select('count(*) as rr');
 foreach($months as $month){
         $this->db->like('lup', $month);
 }
 $query = $this->db->get('trans_email')
```